# how to retrieve image that is stored in database?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code in response of this script i get content on page that content is stored in database but please let me know the way to retrieve that content in image form?

```
$query='SELECT * FROM upload_file';

$result=mysqli_query($con,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<img src=".$row['plaint']." width='100' height='100'></img><br>";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $row['plaint'] ) . '" />';
```

This converts the data to the actual image.